# Markle patricia tree odd key lengh

Tags: go-ethereum, merkle-patricia-tries

I was going through MTP deatils [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree)

Can someone give real scenario example for odd key length?

**"When traversing paths in nibbles, we may end up with an odd number of nibbles to traverse, but because all data is stored in bytes format, it is not possible to differentiate between, for instance, the nibble 1, and the nibbles 01 (both must be stored as <01>). To specify odd length, the partial path is prefixed with a flag."**

Answer (score 0):

The citation does not talk about odd-length keys, but rather about an odd-length partial path. An example would be `[1, 2, 3, 'dog']` - the partial path consists of three nibbles: `1`, `2` and `3` (`'dog'` is the value at that path and does not get included when calculating the path length).